# Highcharts set X axis label on tick

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a stockchart graph with a lot of data like [datetime,value].
But my labels date are placed randomly i think.
When i zoom i would like to see my tick and the date of this tick.

But here i have for example ticks for the 10 jan , 15 jan , 20 jan
and labels will be 9jan, 14jan, 19jan

normally it's a weekly point but sometimes one can have one more or one less so i think tickInterval is not the good way for my case.

Thanks for your help.

[img Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEvv2.png)

Comment: You can use the [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) which allows to customise the ticks positions in dynamic function.

Comment: Try putting `tickmarkPlacement: 'on'` on xAxis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tickInterval does not work for your scenario (because your data is at non-regular intervals) then you could use tickPositions. You could extract the x values from your data, place the x values into an array, assign the array to tickPositions.

Documentation for tickPositions is at...

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: I think it's not the good way too,
I try it and when the zoom is reset i have to many x labels ! but my tick are on the label.
And now with my xvalue in the tickpositions the datetime format stop working

Comment: When using tickPositions, you determine number of tick marks and placement of tick marks. When zoomed in, you may want tick marks at every data point. When zoomed out, you may want to limit tick marks (e.g. every nth data point, or one tick mark per week, etc). You can use events (e.g. chart.events.selection, xAxis.events.setExtremes) to change tickPositions as user zooms.

Comment: Thanks it's look like a bit complicated but i will try this method.
Thanks for your help and time